# expected:<21.0> but was:<21> in JUnit

Tags: java, android, junit

I am trying to test the margins in my Android app. My test is as follows:

```
public void testMargins(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    float expected = dpToPixels( 6.0f );
    lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) celsius.getLayoutParams();
    * assertEquals( expected,lp.leftMargin );
    assertEquals( expected,lp.rightMargin );
    lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fahrenheit.getLayoutParams();
    assertEquals( expected,lp.leftMargin );
    assertEquals( expected,lp.rightMargin );
}
```

I am converting DPs to pixels because `leftMargin` and `rightMargin` are in pixels.  And the method that does this conversion is this:

```
public float dpToPixels(float dp){
    float densityDpi = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    return dp * ( densityDpi / 160.0f );
}
```

But the test fails saying:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<21.0> but was:<21>
```

on the line marked with an asterisk. I tried casting the "actual" value to float but that didn't help.

How do I do this right?

Comment: I m guessing that because `assertEquals( )` uses `.equals( )`, the two values are converted to their corresponding wrapper types and their `.equals( )` returns false. If I replace my test with `assertTrue( expected == lp.leftMargin )`, it works like a charm.

Comment: so `lp.leftMargin=21`? And pixels are usually integer values (not floats, can not use half pixels afaik)? So why not update your function `dpToPixels` to return `int` and tackle the issue at the start instead of in a test

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen but what if DP-to-pixel conversion result is a decimal and needs to be ceil-ed or floor-ed? Returning an `int` would be like forcing a floor, right? :)

Comment: Standard rounding rules apply when converting a float to an int: 0.5=1, 0.49=0. You can apply other rules if needed of course.